# Finding an API for getting lottery numbers from EuroMillions

Tags: javascript, json, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have been trying to create a google assistant interaction for checking to see if the most recently drawn lottery results match the user's

I have tried an API created by 'CreativeSolutions' however the API does not seem to be responding to requests and I cannot find any other alternatives.

```js
'use strict';
 
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 
const app = dialogflow({ debug:true });
 
app.intent('wednesdays number', (conv, {number}) => {

  var lottoNumber = number;
  if (lottoNumber == '01') {
   return conv.ask('Thats correct, want to try again?');
  }
  
 var unirest = require("unirest");

 var req = unirest("GET", "https://euromillions.p.rapidapi.com/ResultsService/FindLast");

 req.headers({
 "x-rapidapi-host": "euromillions.p.rapidapi.com",
 "x-rapidapi-key": "6176bf0ce5mshda3ef945e5d809fp156f41jsnd333104ff8d2"
 });


 req.end(function (res) {
 if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);

 console.log(res.body);
});
  
  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EuroMillions does not have a free public-facing official API so this would be unable to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

But you can use this API on RapidAPI: https://rapidapi.com/jribeiro19/api/euro-millions/
There is a free access to get results and paid access to get some more features.

disclaimer: I'm the developer/owner.